# Elastical camera movement effects in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I want to move a camera to a destination with elastical effects like a rubber band. I have tried this code it moving my object towards the destination           Start from high speed and then slow down gradually but not showing the elastical effects.

```
IEnumerator CamElasticMove()
{
    if (transform.position.x > targetFollow.transform.position.x)
    {
        newPostionAtDistance = new Vector3(targetFollow.transform.position.x + xDistance,
                                            targetFollow.transform.position.y + yDistance,
                                            targetFollow.transform.position.z + zDistance);
    }
    else
    {
        newPostionAtDistance = new Vector3(targetFollow.transform.position.x - xDistance, targetFollow.transform.position.y + yDistance, targetFollow.transform.position.z - zDistance);
    }
    float i = 50, t = 0;
    while (t < 1)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime / i;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPostionAtDistance, t);
        transform.LookAt(targetFollow.transform);
        if (transform.position.ToString() == newPostionAtDistance.ToString())
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Object reached to the point.");
            yield break;
        }

        smoothTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return 0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Picture Description:**

[image]

Comment: just use free tween engines available at Asset Store like DOTween or LeanTween - they will make it really easy :)

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszMotyczka for info but using this packages is a tideous task i will prefer to do my job using my custom code.

Comment: what do you mean by elastical effect? Do you need it to overshoot?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka I have the question with a picture description hope it will help. if it is not then ask